# PagerAdapter using fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-pageradapter

Below is an example of a PagerAdapter.
Is it possible to get fragments and add these to the container instead of writing all logic in instantiateItem ?

Thanks in advance

```
@Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            View view=null;
            if(position%2==0){
                view = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_item,container, false);
            }else{
                view = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_item,container, false);
            }
            // Add the newly created View to the ViewPager
            container.addView(view);

            // Retrieve a TextView from the inflated View, and update it's text
            TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            title.setText(tabs[position]);

            // Return the View
            return view;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use either `FragmentPagerAdapter` (for low amount of pages which will be kept in memory) or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` (for high amount of pages which will be saved if too far from current screen). You need only override `getCount()` and `getItem(int position)` which is supposed to return a new fragment instance based on position.

Docs as well as usage examples:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html

Comment: One thing to keep in mind with either of these adapters is that they are *not* built to handle moving datasets. If you insert or move an item, you need to create a new adapter (not just notify that the dataset changed). 

For other cases they're great, though. :)

Comment: @ kcoppock  THANKS! this has been driving me nuts. I'm not sure how this was supposed to get in my mind without you putting it there.